# SecondViewController Loads Automatically if an alert pops-up the second time after I logout

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uialertcontroller

This project is simple signIn and signUp using JSON data in which when I build the project and test it on simulator for the first time when the view is loaded everything works well as expected.
All alerts are working fine. Here is my alert function

```
func createAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got It", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**After I signIn or signUp a segue is performed to second view controller very smoothly. But when I logout and it comes to first screen, if i don't enter a text for mail or password an alert comes(which is great) but after I press `Got It` the second screen comes up again with the last mail_id entered. That's very shocking.**

I'm using permanent storage to create a session, here is my code for creating session and performing segue to next screen

```
self.token = "\(authToken)"
self.name = ((jsonResult["user"] as? NSDictionary)?["email"] as? String)!
self.session.append(self.token)
self.session.append(self.name)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.session, forKey: "Session")
DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {                                        
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "First Segue", sender: self)
})
```

My logout code in second screen is(also a segue is performed form here to go back on signIn and singUp screen):

```
let session = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Session")
    if let quitSession = session as? [String]{
        var array = quitSession
        array.removeAll()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "Session")
    }
```

In my first screen's **viewDidAppear Method** I'm checking if the user is previously loggedIn or not(Here is the code for it):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let item = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Session")
    let existingSession = (item as? [String])!
    if existingSession.count > 0 {
        let array = existingSession
        name = array[1]
        token = array[0]

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "First Segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I basically think **Alerts is causing this to happen**, as whenever a alert pops-up the second screen comes up with previous loggedIn user.

I also want to mention that after loggingOut I checked weather `UserDefaults` is empty or not(And as expected it is empty).

This bug is coming when I try after logOut and when any Alert comes(eg: For blank textfields).
Thank You.

**Update**

Here is a part of code to show from where I called the `createAlert()` method, as this method is called for various purposes.

```
// To check for Email and Password Fields are not empty
func ifTextFieldDatapresent() -> Bool {
    var returnType = Bool()
    if emailText.text == "" || passwordText.text == "" {
        createAlert(title: "Alert !", message: "Please Enter Correct Email and Password")
        returnType = false
    } else{
        returnType = true
    }
    return returnType
}
```

Comment: from where you are calling create alert function ??

Comment: @NikunjDamani I updated my question for your concern, thanks

Comment: Okay are you making session empty on logout because as per your code in viewDidAppear is checking session is not empty it should show second controller so this might cause the problem.

Comment: @NikunjDamani I thought for the same, that's why I tried to print the `existingSession` value to console and with no surprise it was empty `[]`, even I kept the breakpoint before segue in **viewDidAppear** it didn't stopped there.